# Finding a matrix with the following property

Tags: matrices, symmetry

I have one $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $B$. Let $p$ be a scalar, I want to multiply the diagonal elements of $B$ by $p$. Let now $C$ denote the resultant matrix of the process described. Is there some matrix $A$, such that $AB = C$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $B$ is nonsingular, $A = C B^{-1}$.  Or did you want an $A$ that doesn't depend on $B$ and $C$?  That won't exist.

Comment: so A must depend on B? I try n = 1 and 2. It seems to depend on n though.